# How to mark test as xfail only with specific parameters with Pytest

Tags: testing, pytest

I'm quite new to pytest and I would like to know how to mark a test as "expected to fail" when called with certain parameters. I parametrize test like this:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("param1", [False, True])
@pytest.mark.parametrize("param2", [1, 2, 3])
def test_foo(self, param1, param2):
    ...
```

What I'm trying to achieve is that when the test is called with `(param1 == True and param2 == 2)`, the test should fail; whilst any other parameter combinations should pass.

But I haven't found any way to do this. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 50):

See [xfail with parametrize](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/how-to/skipping.html#skip-xfail-with-parametrize):

```py
@pytest.mark.parametrize("param2, param2", [
    (1, True),
    (2, True),
    pytest.param(1, False, marks=pytest.mark.xfail(reason='some bug')),
])
def test_foo(self, param1, param2):
    ...
```

Comment: FYI for others: I tried to use the `pytest.param` approach in the docs, but was getting "`param` not in module" - type of error. Not sure if I am outdated on my `pytest` version but something to try if you encounter this. The `pytest.mark.xfail` approach worked for me.

Comment: You are right, probably you had an outdated pytest. `pytest.param` was introduced in `3.2`.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in 3.1.2 ?  I was able to put the xfail mark outside the parametrize, though (all of the cases were expected to fail.)

Comment: If I squint my eyes, I can see the answer trying to take form.  When I read the actual text, I'm completely confused: why (`"param2, param2"` and not `"param2, param1"`?  Why `pytest.param(1, False, ...` and not `pytest.param(2, True, ...`?  When and how is param2 allowed to be 3?  So many questions...